# How to invoke a method with null parameter value using reflection in groovy?

Tags: java, reflection, groovy

I use groovy and junit to write unit tests. I wrote a method, `testBrandIDParam`, to test some common cases like `null` parameter value or `paramID < 0` using reflection. However, when I test `null` param, this method doesn't always work. How can I solve this problem?

```
@Test
public void testGetDetailBrand() {
    GetDetailReqDTO reqDTO = new GetDetailReqDTO();
    testBrandIDParam(reqDTO, service, "getDetailBrand");
}

private <T> void testBrandIDParam(T requestDTO, Service service, String testMethod) {
    Class requestClazz = requestDTO.getClass();
    Class serviceClazz = service.getClass();
    java.lang.reflect.Method doTestMethod = serviceClazz.getMethod(testMethod, requestDTO.class);

    // test null
    CommonRespDTO respDTO = doTestMethod.invoke(service,{null });
    Assert.assertTrue(respDTO.getRespCode() == ICommonRespDTO.ResponseCode.FAIL.getCode());

    T reqInstance = (T) requestClazz.newInstance();
    // req-ID = 0
    respDTO = (CommonRespDTO) doTestMethod.invoke(service, reqInstance)
    Assert.assertTrue(!respDTO.isSuccess());

    brandIDField.setAccessible(false);
}
```

Note: `getDetailBrand()` has only one argument, `brandID`.

1. `CommonRespDTO respDTO = doTestMethod.invoke(service,{null });`
   throws

   > java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
2. `CommonRespDTO respDTO = doTestMethod.invoke(service,new Object[1]{ null });`
   throws

   > groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: [Ljava.lang.Object;.call() is applicable for argument types: (service.serviceTest$_testBrandIDParam_closure1) values: [service.serviceTest$_testBrandIDParam_closure1@28236ebc]
   >   Possible solutions: tail(), wait(), any(), max(), last(), wait(long)
3. `CommonRespDTO respDTO = doTestMethod.invoke(service,new Object[1]{ null });`
   produces compile error:

   > new Objecy[] cannot be applied to groovy.lang.Closure

Comment: It's very difficult to tell what you're asking, but my best guess is that you're using the Java array syntax `{}` instead of `[]` for Groovy.

Comment: how can I invoke method with null param in groovy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass an array of `Object`s into `invoke()`. It's a little tricky:

```
doTestMethod.invoke(service, [null] as Object[])
```

Comment: Thanks.It really works.